# How to copy Movieclip display properties as a vector into another movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3

For my project I need to copy the graphics of a Movieclip with all of its children without copying anything else into a second Movieclip. I cannot use the Bitmap classes because I need the graphics to be displayed as a vector and I cannot use a method that simply copies the clip by calling the instructor ie:

var copy:MovieClip = clip.constructor

Is there any way to copy only the display portions of a clip into another Movieclip without turning it into a bitmap?

Thanks

Comment: I did a bit of investigating on this today, and it really comes down to cloning shape data, which unfortunately -- doesn't seem to be possible. (at least not in a simple way).  My question is, how much data on the movieclip you want to create a copy of, will be modified from the initial movieclip at creation ? If it's just x,y,rotation,visible, alpha etc. You might want to go that route -- create a new object and manually make those changes. Unless the object you are trying to copy is comprised of graphics data that you have drawn at runtime. In that case, this won't work.

Comment: I've unfortunately tied some of the functionality in my program to these display objects, so if I try to simply instantiate a second copy of them I'm in a lot of trouble. I need to somehow copy out only the graphics in the object, similar to what the BitmapData class does, but I would like it to be in vector format so that I can scale it. I'm starting to think this isn't possible.

Comment: This specific functionality might not be possible, but this is the kind of thing where a new design concept might be the solution. Hard to say without having a better idea of the current design requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloning display objects out of the box in as3 is no easy task. Here is a tutorial explaining the several approaches that have been attempted over the years and what works and what does not:

http://www.dannyburbol.com/2009/01/movieclip-clone-flash-as3/

Comment: Yeah, I've seen this. Unfortunately I can't use the solution he finally arrived at because I have constructors on some of the children of my movie clip that take arguments.

Comment: If it's just the graphics you need to copy, use the graphics.copyFrom() method. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#copyFrom().

Comment: I believe graphics.copyFrom() only copies graphics that are drawn using the methods in the Graphics class. It doesn't seem to work when trying to copy over the graphics of pre-drawn movieclips.